# Web API route being ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have these two routes defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetVoucherTypesForPartner",
    url: "api/Partner/{partnerId}/VoucherType",
    defaults: new { controller = "Partner", action = "GetVoucherTypesForPartner"}
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

In my `PartnerProfile` controller, I have 2 methods:

```
public Partner Get(string id)
{ }

public IEnumerable<string> GetVoucherTypesForPartner(string id)
{ }
```

If I hit the url `~/api/Partner/1234` then, as expected, the `Get` method is called.
However, if I hit the url `~/api/Partner/1234/VoucherType` then the same `Get` method is called. I am expecting my `GetVoucherTypesForPartner` to be called instead.

I'm pretty sure something in my route setup is wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have mapped standard MVC routes, not Web API routes. There's a big difference. The standard routes are used by controllers deriving from the `Controller` class, but if you are using the ASP.NET Web API and your controllers are deriving from the `ApiController` type then you should define HTTP routes.

You should do that in your `~/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` and not inside your `~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`.

So go ahead:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetVoucherTypesForPartner",
            routeTemplate: "api/Partner/{partnerId}/VoucherType",
            defaults: new { controller = "Partner", action = "GetVoucherTypesForPartner" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public class PartnerController : ApiController
{
    public Partner Get(string id)
    {
        ...
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetVoucherTypesForPartner(string partnerId)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Things to notice:

- We have defined HTTP routes not standard MVC routes
- The parameter that the `GetVoucherTypesForPartner` action takes must be called `partnerId` instead of `id` in order to respect your route definition and avoid any confusions

Comment: Then of course this is not true in ASP.NET Core where there is a single routing.